# What is the new format of documentation comments in Swift 2? (XCode 7 beta 3)

Tags: swift, documentation, comments, swift2, xcode7

There is this [great article](http://nshipster.com/swift-documentation/) by Nate Cook and Mattt Thompson that describes the format of documentation comments in Swift.

However, since Swift 2 in XCode 7 beta some parts of it do not seem to work any more.  For example `:param:` and `:returns:` do not produce desired result (they are simply rendered as-is instead).

Other parts seem do keep working, though (i.e. both types of comments in `/// ...` or `/** ... */` style, code-blocks, lists), but no way to mark up the documentation into similar sections like the core API has.

Does someone know if there is a way to highlight method parameters and returned results (what `:param:` and `:returns:` did in the past) in documentation comments in Swift 2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're looking for `Symbol Documentation Markup Syntax`, meaning if you want to know the new syntax (Xcode 7) to write documentation for your methods using Markdown, there is the [Markup Formatting Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497)  on Apple's website.

Here's how you define a **Block Comment** :

```
/**
  line of text with optional markup commands
  …
  line of text with optional markup commands
*/
```

And here's an example of a comment with the most important tags :

```
/**
  Just testing documentation using Markdown
  - returns: Bool
  - parameter param1:String
  - parameter param2:String
  - Throws: error lists
*/
```

And here's the short format

```
/// line of text with optional markup commands
```

Comment: What about the parameters of a block parameter?

Answer (score 8):

[What’s new in Xcode 7.](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) gives a hint

> Markdown comments shown as rich text in Quick Help with embedded
>   images and links.

and the Xcode 7 beta release notes state:

> Swift documentation comments use a syntax based on the Markdown
>   format, aligning them with rich comments in playgrounds. (20180161)

followed by a short description.

As an example,

```
/**
    Repeats a string `times` times.

    :param: str     The string to repeat.
    :param: times   The number of times to repeat `str`.

    :returns: A new string with `str` repeated `times` times.
*/
func repeatString(str: String, times: Int) -> String {
    return join("", Array(count: times, repeatedValue: str))
}
```

from http://nshipster.com/swift-documentation/ would now be written as

```
/// Repeats a string `times` times.

/// - Parameters:
///     - str:     The string to repeat.
///     - times:   The number of times to repeat `str`.
/// - returns: A new string with `str` repeated `times` times.
func repeatString(str: String, times: Int) -> String {
   return Repeat(count: times, repeatedValue: str).joinWithSeparator("")
}
```

Or with multiline comment:

```
/**
    Repeats a string `times` times.

    - Parameter str:   The string to repeat.
    - Parameter times: The number of times to repeat `str`.
    - returns: A new string with `str` repeated `times` times. 
*/
func repeatString(str: String, times: Int) -> String {
    return Repeat(count: times, repeatedValue: str).joinWithSeparator("")
}
```

For more information on Markdown, see

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown
- http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/

and much of

- [Playground Markup Format for Comments](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Playground_Ref/Chapters/MarkupReference.html)

applies to inline documentation comments as well.

For example, you could add

```
     **Important:** `times` must not be negative.
```

where "Important" is rendered **strong**.

Answer (score 4):

In Xcode 7 beta 4 a list of parameters can only be written like this:

```
 - parameter str:     The string to repeat.
 - parameter times:   The number of times to repeat `str`.
```

(This should be a comment on [Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31366052/1060023)s post but I don't have the reputation to do so.)

Comment: THIS. I was pulling my hair about **why** `:param:` renders as ":param:"!!

Comment: It's perfectly fine to extend someone else answer as long as your adding something valuable. Looks fine to me. :)